# CoreData Exc_bad_access code=1 with Sub Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I need your help, I still have an beautiful `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on this line `self.clinic!.copyWithDTO(clinicDTO)`.

Console : `po self.clinic`

```
Optional(<NSManagedObject: 0x7a7bd240> (entity: Clinic; id: 0x7a7bbe10 <x-coredata://7B916AD3-1989-426F-932F-0A62C755F2B4/Clinic/p1> ; data: <fault>))
```

I'm trying to fill properties on a sub entity in CoreData model by giving a DTO.

```
@objc(UserProfile)
class UserProfile: BaseStoredObject {

    override class func entityName() -> String {
        return "UserProfile"
    }

    override func copyWithDTO(dto: BaseDTO) {
        if let userProfileDTO = dto as? UserProfileDTO {
            self.id = userProfileDTO.id
            self.login = userProfileDTO.login
            self.password = userProfileDTO.password
            self.lastname = userProfileDTO.lastname
            self.email = userProfileDTO.email
            self.createdOn = userProfileDTO.createdOn
            self.gender = userProfileDTO.gender
            self.userProfileType = userProfileDTO.userProfileType
            self.firstname = userProfileDTO.firstname
            self.fullname = userProfileDTO.fullname
            if let clinicDTO = userProfileDTO.clinic {
                if let unwrappedClinic = self.clinic {
                    unwrappedClinic.copyWithDTO(clinicDTO)
                } else {
                    self.clinic = Clinic(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Clinic", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
                    self.clinic!.copyWithDTO(clinicDTO) //  !! EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x....)
                }

            }
        } else {
            fatalError("copyWithDTO: must be sent with UserProfileDTO")
        }
    }

}

@objc(Clinic)
class Clinic: BaseStoredObject {

    override class func entityName() -> String {
        return "Clinic"
    }

    override func copyWithDTO(dto: BaseDTO) {
        if let clinicDTO = dto as? ClinicDTO {
            self.id = clinicDTO.id
            self.name = clinicDTO.name
            self.phoneNumber = clinicDTO.phoneNumber
            self.phoneNumber24hours = clinicDTO.phoneNumber24hours
            self.nurseContactPhoneNumber = clinicDTO.nurseContactPhoneNumber
            self.emergencyPhoneNumber = clinicDTO.emergencyPhoneNumber
            self.internalClinicId = clinicDTO.internalClinicId
            self.webserviceURL = ""
        } else {
            fatalError("copyWithDTO: must be sent with ClinicDTO")
        }
    }

}


extension UserProfile {

    @NSManaged var id: String?

    @NSManaged var login: String?
    @NSManaged var password: String?
    @NSManaged var lastname: String?
    @NSManaged var firstname: String?
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var createdOn: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var userProfileType: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var gender: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var fullname: String?

    @NSManaged var clinic: Clinic?

}
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you ;)

**EDIT:** `BaseStoredObject` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`

Comment: Check in the Data Model Editor that the entity Clinic has the correct class (ie Clinic) specified.

Comment: Yes, it was.. Finally I added MOGenerator on my project to get out from this bug. So now it's ok but I didn't now what was this issue